# multiple knapsack problem?

Tags: optimization, algorithms, nonlinear-optimization, recursive-algorithms

I have a weight X. This should be distributed into multiple knapsacks w1...wY.
It should be distributed to the largest knapsacks first and smallest last.
Yet the optimal distribution should be found leaving ideally the smallest unused space.

Example:

```
X = 17 -> w7, w5 -> w7 = 3, w5 = 0 -> unused 4 (wrong)
X = 17 -> w7, w5 -> w7 = 2, w5 = 1 -> unused 2 (wrong)
X = 17 -> w7, w5 -> w7 = 1, w5 = 2 -> unused 0 (correct)

X = 15 -> w7, w5 -> w7 = 0, w5 = 3 -> unused 0 (correct)

X = 14 -> w7, w5 -> w7 = 2, w5 = 0 -> unused 0 (correct)

X = 13 -> w7, w5 -> w7 = 1, w5 = 2 -> unused 4 (wrong)
X = 13 -> w7, w5 -> w7 = 2, w5 = 0 -> unused 1 (correct)
```

What algorithm could be used?
I think this is a variant of the knapsack problem and possibly can be solved by a variation of it?
The wikipedia article also mentions this but doesn't feature a solution.

---

After considering the comment, I think this should solve the problem:

Given w1...wY and weight X.

```
w1 + w2 + ... wY = Z

X - Z = 0 -> equal distribution
X - Z = A
    A / wY = integer
        (X - wY)/wY = count wY -> start over with w1 + w2 + ...w(Y-1), X - (A * wY) = X
    A / wY = float -> start over with w1 + w2 + ...w(Y-1), X - A = X
```

Comment: what is the meaning of a line like `X = 17 -> w7, w5 -> w7 = 3, w5 = 0 -> unused 4 (wrong)`

Comment: weight x is 17. knapsack available are w5 with size 5 and w7 with size 7. you can fit 17 in 3 knapsack with size 7 (w7) but that leaves size 4 unused in one knapsack.

Comment: can you tell more about the problem? What is the source of this problem, what is the size of the values involved, why should the largest knapsack be filled first? Why did you tag it 'recurive-algorithm'?

Comment: It seems that you want to solve an [integer programming problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming)
$$
\begin{array}   \\
 x,y \in \mathbb{Z} \\
    x \ge 0 \\
    y \ge 0 \\
    7x + 5y -17 \ge  0 \\
    7x + 5y  \to\min 
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Thanks! I think this is the solution. Sorry I'm a developer no mathematician so I struggle a bit setting up the correct format. But I'll edit my question. Please add it as an answer if you think this is correct, so I can mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to solve an [integer programming problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming)
\begin{array}   \\  x,y \in \mathbb{Z} \\     x \ge 0 \\     y \ge 0 \\     7x + 5y -17 \ge  0 \\     7x + 5y  \to\min  \end{array}